# Postgres: Create duplicates of existing rows, changing one value?

Tags: postgresql

I am working in Postgres 9.4. I have a table that looks like this:

```
     Column      │         Type         │                             Modifiers
─────────────────┼──────────────────────┼───────────────────────
 id              │ integer              │ not null default 
 total_list_size │ integer              │ not null
 date            │ date                 │ not null
 pct_id          │ character varying(3) │
```

I want to take all values where `date='2015-09-01'`, and create identical new entries with the date `2015-10-01`.

How can I best do this?

I can get the list of values to copy with `SELECT * from mytable WHERE date='2015-09-01'`, but I'm not sure what to do after that.

Comment: Is `id` column serial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the column `id` is `serial` then

```
INSERT INTO mytable (total_list_size, date, pct_id)
SELECT total_list_size, '2015-10-01', pct_id
FROM mytable 
WHERE date = '2015-09-01';
```

else, if you want the `ids` to be duplicated:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, total_list_size, date, pct_id)
SELECT id, total_list_size, '2015-10-01', pct_id
FROM mytable 
WHERE date = '2015-09-01';
```